# How do I doubleclick on gridcell?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I want to doubleclick on particular gridcell, and after I searched the element by google chrome developer tools(select an element), the element on which I want to doubleclick comes out like this.

```
<td class="w2grid_input_table gridBodyDefault gridBodyDefault_data grd_mst_columnstyle_19_ w2grid_default_readonly" id="grd_mst_cell_3_19" role="gridcell" style="height: 24px;" rowspan="2" colindex="21" col_id="D_16" displaymode="label" blockselect="false" inputtype="text" or_wd="30" datatype="text" tdIndex="143" or_bgColor="">
<nobr class="w2grid_input w2grid_input_readonly">/</nobr>
</td>
```

How can I doubleclick on this gridcell element by writing code on 'console' section?

I have tried these.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('w2grid_input_table gridBodyDefault gridBodyDefault_data grd_mst_columnstyle_19_ w2grid_default_readonly');
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I'm unsure as to whether you wish to handle a double click event or simulate such an event so my answer includes example code for both. For future reference, the [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) is a great resource for learning how to use JavaScript browser APIs.

If you want to simulate a double click event you can use a function such as this:

```js
function simulateDoubleClick(target) {
  const event = new MouseEvent('dblclick', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });
  const cancelled = !target.dispatchEvent(event);

  if (cancelled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault.
    alert("cancelled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
    alert("not cancelled");
  }
}

// Get a handle on the DOM element
const element = document.getElementById('id-of-html-element');
// Simulate the double click event
simulateDoubleClick(element);
```

See [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#triggering_built-in_events) for more details.

If you want to execute a function in response to a double click event on a element then you need to use an event listener for the `dblclick` event. See [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event).

```js
// Define an event handler function
const handler = (event) => {
    console.log(`${event.target} was double clicked!`);
};

// Attach event handler to element
const elem = document.querySelector('#doubleClickMe');
elem.addEventListener('dblclick', handler);
```